# Greater than one line git commit messages

Tags: git, jira

We are using git with Eclipse (graphic git).  Our commit statements have a description and then a Change ID.  Our description must have a JIRA story at the beginning.

My problem is I can never have more than  one line in the commit or it will complain (see the image below).  This is actually just one line but the word "field" wrapped around.  You cannot get very descriptive with one line.  Does anyone know a way around this?

[image]

Comment: This is hard. Try to be brief in the header line. You can get as descriptive as you want in the body.

Comment: Is the whole „ATEST-14871 update input fields for group“ the mandatory JIRA story? Then this seems redundant (the numeric code should be all that is needed as an identifier) and this is a stupid requirement.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the body of the message? The log should let you have a short header line, a blank line, and then as much text as you want from the 3rd line on with details. That's how we work anyway: use a brief summary header line, shown in one-line views of the logs, and put more details if needed in the body, shown on multi-line views of the logs.

Comment: This is because Eclipse is (correctlly) hard wrapping your title to the 50 or so character limit.
Then correctly warning you. You should try rewriting you header so it's more concise and moving the rest the the body of the commit. If this is against protocol for the project you should raise that and have it looked at and changed.
Leaving the second line blank is more important than your companies policies because it will be git logs if not done.

Answer (score 5):

While using Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a) came across this issue.

Found [Bug 471421 - Commit message warning in Git Staging View is wrong](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=471421) which contains the suggested work-around which did suppress the warning when entered a title of more than 50 characters:

> Unselecting "Hard-wrap commit message" in Team/Git/Committing preferences panel solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Git docs says in [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion) (emphasis mine):

> Though not required, it’s a good idea to begin the commit message with a single short (less than 50 character) line summarizing the change, followed by a blank line and then a more thorough description. **The text up to the first blank line in a commit message is treated as the commit title**, and that title is used throughout Git. For example, git-format-patch[1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#_discussion) turns a commit into email, and it uses the title on the Subject line and the rest of the commit in the body.

So git itself *does* handles several "physical" lines up to the first empty line as **one** "logical" line and displays this e.g. with `git log --oneline`. Other tools might or might not do that.

Therefore you can just ignore the warning.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your message editor is adding a hard line break when the first line is too long. The fix is to keep the first line shorter. If you need additional explanation, add a blank line and then the text before the Change-Id.

Comment: You shouldn't add text after the change id. The change id should typically be the last thing in a git commit message. See [this description](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/user-changeid.html#_description). Better to add extra text before the change ID, while making sure to have a blank line between the header line and the extra text.

Comment: @Alderath Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my answer. I'm not familiar with Change IDs.